# jQuery object ".attr('href')" returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have 2 links on my page. I'm trying to change the text of linkB when linkA is clicked. However, whenever I try to get the 'href' value of linkB, I'm getting an undefined error. I've been through a bunch of other threads here, but none have worked. Forgive me if I'm missing something obvious.

```
        <a ID="lnkPopUp" runat="server" style="text-decoration: underline; text-align: right" target="_blank">
            New Window
        </a>
        <br/>
        <a ID="lnkAlt" runat="server" style="text-decoration: underline; text-align: right" target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">
            Not this one
        </a>
```

My script:

```
$('#lnkPopUp').click(
            function () {               
                var addressVal = $('#lnkAlt').attr('href');
                alert(addressVal);    
            }  

        );
```

Also, I've got my script inside the `<head>` tags. Could it be trying to get the href before the rest of the page has been processed and the href has been set?

Please let me know if any other info might help!

Comment: where are you setting the href value??

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/n52b3k8p/

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `clientIDMode` so that jquery is using the right ID.

```
<a ID="lnkAlt" clientIDMode="static" runat="server" style="text-decoration: underline; text-align: right" target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">
    Not this one
</a>
```

Comment: Yeah I'd have a hunch its probably the ClientIdMode too. As noted try setting it to static, use Developer Tools or Firebug to actually have a look at the rendered HTML and look for the actual name of the lnkPopUp/lnkAlt controls.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `.Net Framework 3.5` or lower `clientIDMode` is not going to work, because the property was added in `.Net Framework 4`

Try with this

```
   $('#lnkPopUp').click(
        function () {               
            var addressVal = $('#<%= lnkAlt.ClientID %>').attr('href');
            alert(addressVal);    
        }  
    );
```

and to change the href attribute use this code

```
$('#<%= lnkAlt.ClientID %>').attr("href", "http://stackoverflow.com/")
```

You have to use `<%= lnkAlt.ClientID %>` to get the generated ID; ASP.Net change the control's ID in the HTML generated